# Find top-most following elements with XPath

Tags: python, html, xml, xpath, lxml

In XPath, I know I can select all following elements with `/following::*`, however I'd like to ***avoid*** also selecting the children contained within any following elements.

For example, given this document:

```html
<body>
    <div id="div1">
        <p id="p1">...</p>
        <p id="p2">
            <span id="span1"></span>
            <span id="span2"><i id="i1">...</i></span>
        </p>
        <p id="p3">...</p>
    </div>
    <div id="div2">
        <p id="p4">...</p>
        <p id="p5">...</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

If I have `span1` selected, I would like to select `span2` (but not `i1`), `p3`, and `div2` (but not `p4` or `p5`).

In Python, my code might look something like:

```py
>>> lxml.html.fromstring(document).xpath('//*[@id="span1"]/following::*')
[<Element span at 0x1082bd680>,
 <Element i at 0x1082bd4f0>,
 <Element p at 0x1082bd770>,
 <Element div at 0x1082bd360>,
 <Element p at 0x1082bd7c0>,
 <Element p at 0x1082bdef0>]
```

But what I'd like to have returned is:

```py
[<Element span at 0x1082bd680>,
 <Element p at 0x1082bd770>,
 <Element div at 0x1082bd360>]
```

---

EDIT: @kjhughes answer got me 90% of the way there. Because the real life example might not have a ID that I can easily use to match, I ended up writing code like:

```py
find_following = lxml.html.etree.XPath(
    "following::*[not(../preceding::*[. = node()])]"
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This XPath,

```xml
//*[@id="span1"]/following::*[not(../preceding::*[@id="span1"])]
```

selects the elements following the targeted `span` element whose parents do not have the targeted `span` element as a predecessor,

```
<span id="span2"><i id="i1">...</i></span>
<p id="p3">...</p>
<div id="div2"> <p id="p4">...</p> <p id="p5">...</p> </div>
```

as requested.

Comment: thanks! If I wanted to make a function that would take an element and then select all following elements without also select any children, do you think something like this would also work: `./following-sibling::* | ./following::*[not(../preceding::*)]`? (In my actual code I don't really have an ID that I can easily query)

Comment: If that works better for your actual code, great.  Let me know if you encounter any problems.

Answer (score 0):

XPath 3.1 has the function `outermost()`: `outermost(following::*)` selects all following elements excluding any that are descendants of another element in the node-set.

XPath 2.0 allows `following::* except following::*/descendant::*`.

In XPath 1.0 you can express `($A except $B)` as `$A[count(.|$B)=count($B)]`. (Though this isn't all that useful because there's no way within XPath itself of binding a variable).